# How to send temp table records to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

> Trying this query but not working fine some of records are missing,
>   What i'm doing is, Reading recent text file from drive folder and
>   inserting to temp table. When i run program , all records came to temp
>   table properly, now i want send them to main table , if records are
>   already present in main they should not b copied, how to do that??

```
insert into tblMain
select EnNo,DateTime from tblAllTempRecords
where  DateTime not in(select DateTime from tblMain)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use except

```
INSERT INTO tblMain
SELECT EnNo, DATETIME
FROM tblAllTempRecords

EXCEPT

SELECT EnNo, DATETIME
FROM tblMain
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need a correlation in your subquery:

```
insert into tblMain
    select EnNo, DateTime
    from tblAllTempRecords tr
    where DateTime not in (select DateTime from tblMain m where tr.EnNo = m.EnNo)
```

There are other ways to write this.  For instance, if either column could have negative values, then `not exists` is preferable to `not in`.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you need

```
    insert into tblMain
select EnNo,DateTime 
from tblMain as t right JOIN tblAllTempRecords AS t1
ON t.EnNo = t1.EnNo
AND t.EnNo is null
```